# Error while install Az module in Powershell - Package 'Az.Accounts' failed to be installed

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I come across an error message while installing Az module in Powershell in Windows 10. Any ideas?
Command used:

```
Install-Module Az -AllowClobber
```

Error message:

> Package 'Az.Accounts' failed to be installed because: End of Central
>   Directory record could not be found.

[image]

Comment: Could you please have a try to re-open the powershell with administrator ?

Comment: It was run with administrator. After re-open the powershell with administrator and run the same command, it works. Don't know why. Anway, issue fixed. If you put it to the answer , I will accept it.

Comment: Same here.  Fails to install when running as admin the first time.  Two times are a charm...?  When at first you don't succeed...?

Comment: Really strange. Don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, just re-open the powershell with administrator, it will work.